# Disable "You'll need to provide administrator permission" prompt in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, administrator, uac

I'm just bored clicking on the CONTINUE button every time "You'll need to provide administrator permission" prompt appears, as I'm the only administrator of the PC. I've configured Notification system to 'Never Notify' from **Control Panel -> UAC** but still no luck.
I've to face the problem when copying / moving / renaming file on an additional internal disk.

Comment: Give the require rights to perform the action on the user you are using.

Comment: I had this problem with a locked drive (western digital). It was a bug (the computer went in sleep mode and waked up, the drive looked unlocked, but wasn't). I ejected the drive and unlocked it using the password, then it did not bother me with admin permission.

Answer (score 8):

You are not allowed to take ownership of many files like `C:\Users`, `C:\bootmgr`, `C:\hiberfile.sys`, `pagefile.sys`, `C:\Program Files`, etc., and thereby even the `C:\` drive as a whole. Also, setting permissions isn't disabling the admin prompt, it's simply attempting to sidestep the issue instead.

Here is the actual solution: Disabling the prompt

For Windows 7 Ultimate, Business or Enterprise edition which has Local Group Policy, or computer joined to domain and has Active Directory-based GPO, the group policy can be used to disable UAC for local computer or many computer across large networks at once.

1. Enter GPedit.msc in Start Search to run Local Group Policy editor. (Or gpmc.msc to run Group Policy Management Console for AD-based domain GPO editor).
2. Navigate to the following tree branch:

   > Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options

   In GPMC, browse to the required GPO which is linked to the domain or OU where the policy wants to apply.
3. Locate the following policy in the right pane:

   > User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode
4. Set its value to Elevate without prompt.
5. Locate the following policy in the right pane:

   > User Account Control: Detect application installations and prompt for elevation
6. Set its value to Disabled.
7. Locate the following policy in the right pane:

   > User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode
8. Set its value to Disabled.
9. Locate the following policy in the right pane:

   > User Account Control: Only elevate UIAccess applications that are installed in secure locations
10. Set its value to Disabled.
11. Disable UAC with Group Policy
12. Restart the computer when done.

Answer (score 4):

You could [take ownership](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/) of the *internal* folder you use.

Answer (score 3):

I also had to figure it out and I thought I would share the answer:

1. Go to windows explorer
2. Right mouse the drive in question
3. Go to properties
4. Select security tab.
5. Change permissions to full

Answer (score 3):

According to [this article](http://www.techtipsmag.com/fix-youll-need-to-provide-administrator-permission-to-copy-to-this-folder-error/) there may be some issues with Metro apps, but disabling UAC using regedit worked for me.  To do so, start regedit (by typing `regedit` in the run command) and navigate to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

Change the value of the entry `EnableLUA` to `0`.  Then restart your machine.  Upon doing this, I never get nagged with a dialog to "provide administrator permission" anymore.

Comment: Does this do anything different than changing the UAC setting normally? Both require administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding my domain user account that I login with to the Administrator group.  This worked on Windows 10; not sure it will work for Windows 7.

Answer (score -1):

goto command prompt (admin)
once the command prompt comes up type:
sc config secdrv start= demand (hit enter)
then type:
sc start secdrv (hit enter)
now run your game are whatever you needed permission for.

Answer (score -1):

I just came across this issue when cloning a repo in GitHub Desktop. Cloning to inetpub isn't allowed. Not sure this is relevant for the case in the original question (copying / moving / renaming files) but the solution for me was to right click GitHub Desktop and select "Run as Administrator". This is the case for the hosts file with Notepad++ or Sublime too - can't edit the file without running as administrator first. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ever so much for the anonymous, description-less downvote, whoever did that!