# How to disable shield icon in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, user-accounts

[image: Shield Icon]

Just installed windows 10 and I get these annoying shield icons whenever I create shortcuts to a desktop. What is causing it and how can I disable it for all icons?

Edit: after suggested methods still unsolved... Why does windows make it so complicated?
**Edit2: I FINALLY FOUND THE** [**SOLUTION!!**](https://superuser.com/a/1004965/321858)

P.S. If you're on Home edition, I don't think you have Local Security Policy editor available. Also if the icons remain the same just right click go to properties, change icon, select any icon and press ok.

**Edit3:** Found the solution but ran into bigger issue. When I try to open any windows related app it says: This app can't be opened using the built-in administrator....can't even open pictures...
What a shame Windows 10

Comment: It indicates the program needs to run elevated. It should not appear on all programs.

Comment: @DanielB yes it does not appear on some programs. Is there any way to completely disable this nosense?

Comment: It's no nonsense. It's a security feature.

Comment: @Mario The Shield icon is the nonsense. He isn't trying to make everything run non-elevated (if there is such a thing). Unfortunately, the answer by you just removes one of Windows more important security features.

Comment: This same question has been asked [here](http://superuser.com/q/68345/573485).

Answer (score -2):

The shield icon indicates that a program may only be started using elevated privileges (read: administrator access).

This is part of the **User Account Control** (*UAC*).

If you really want to disable it, open your start menu, type `UAC` and open the first and only result, which should be the User Account Control Settings.

You'll find a slider to adjust the security settings. Drop it down to the lowest setting to essentially restore Window's classic behavior of never asking.

**Keep in mind that disabling UAC will put you at severe higher risk from malware such as ransomware. Do so at your own risk.**

Comment: I already did that as soon as I installed windows...

Comment: Oh I think I got it, The programs which were installed prior to me disabling the UAC still have that shield overlay, but newly installed programs don't have it anymore.

Comment: @Giancarlo That shouldn't actually be the case. It really just depends on the individual program.

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/a/68419/573485) answer to  question clears the UAC Badge without removing a single security feature.

Comment: yeah....I still get that icon, it depends on program...so annoying...

Comment: -1 for recommending disabling an important security feature to make the desktop prettier.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov F*** this security feature, I dind't ask for it to be there. I'm in control of the computer, I decide what programs I want to install, I'm the manager of this computer, I'm the one who knocks. I don't like it when windows does something without my consent. I will do everything to disable this bu*****t..

Comment: @XiongChiamiov To be honest I assumed this is about the UAC prompt. As mentioned, I'm aware this has no influence on the icon overlay. Also there's a clear warning about this.

Comment: "I'm in control of the computer, I decide what programs I want to install" -- That's the problem, you're not:  you're explicitly *disabling* the tool that prevents software from pretending to be you and installing things without your consent.  You **really** need to understand what UAC is before disabling it.